# MySql table name concatenation

Tags: php, mysql

I need to define a table name when creating in MySQL, the first part is a defined prefix and last part is my own table name, I'd like to avoid creating an additional variable to hold them both before passing them to my query.

My code is wrapped in a class, I have defined my table name a `private static` variable, my code looks valid but doesn't work.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
CREATE TABLE '$wpdb->prefix.self::$table'     // doesn't work
CREATE TABLE self::$table                     // doesn't work
CREATE TABLE $wpdb->prefix                    // works
CREATE TABLE {$wpdb->prefix.self::$table}     // error
CREATE TABLE $wpdb->prefix.self::$table       // just stupid

$tableName = $wpdb->prefix.self::$table;
CREATE TABLE $tableName                       // works
```

Can anybody give me a knowledge concussion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A static property will not be properly interpolated inside a double-quoted string.  You need to concatenate it.

```
"CREATE TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}" . self::$table;
```

Comment: Aww, that's what I was trying to avoid :(.

Comment: @Solenoid I would probably just define the table name as a variable in every function call then, as in your working example. `$tableName = $wpdb->prefix.self::$table;`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE {$wpdb->prefix}".{self::$table};
```

Note curly braces and no `.` between `$wpdb->prefix` and `self::$table`

Comment: Nope, doesn't work, tried but forgot to add to the list. But since "CREATE TABLE self::$table" doesn't work the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: This will probably give `Notice: undefined variable $table`.

Comment: Do you have static variable `$table` declared in your class?

Comment: @J0HN: first thing in my class: private static $table = 'workdammit';

Comment: Hmmm, and what about table definition? `Create table Table` is not sufficient to create it. Should be something like `Create table Table as (id int)`.